# Problema responsive css

Tags: css

Me gustaria saber porque cuando estoy en 1280px se queda con las reglas de 1440px.

```css
@media (max-width: 1440px){
.fondo_slide {
    top: 65px;
    width: 285px;
    left: 143px;
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
}
 @media (max-width: 1280px){
.fondo_slide {
    top: 35px;
    width: 265px;
    left: 122px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 1024px){
.fondo_slide {
    top: 37px;
    width: 187px;
    left: 93px;
    border: 1px solid green;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo_slide">
  
</div>
```

Me gustaria saber cual es el fallo en el css

Comment: No sé si eso solucionaría el error, pero si usas `css` normal, deberías anidar entre llaves los elementos/propiedades para cada resolución: `@media(max-width: 1440px) {elemento {propiedades}}`, te puede dar problemas sino

Comment: No ese fallo no es esta asi puesto lo que pasa que lo puse mal

Comment: yo te estaba respondiendo con lo mismo que te ha comentado el compañero, el caso es a 1280px exactos te continua con las reglas de 1440px o a 1279px ya coge bien el css de 1280px?

Comment: en 1279 sigue con las reglas de 1440 y si me voy a 1024 tambien sigue con 1440

Comment: Has probado a ponerlo al reves? de la menor resolución a la mayor?

Comment: @daniellandete He metido tu código en un snippet para que veas que funciona correctamente. ¿Lo tienes exactamente igual en el archivo? Igual puedes ver el fallo ahí, ¿o igual es que no funciona como tu crees que debería funcionar? Si es así explícanos que es lo que tu crees/quieres que pase

Comment: ¿Por qué no pruebas a poner lo siguiente? `@media (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1025px)` y haces lo mismo con el resto, así pones un rango

Answer (score 2):

Considerando solamente el código **CSS** que nos pasas, no debería de darte ningún problema y las **mediaqueries** se deberían de estar aplicando con normalidad. He montado un ejemplo, que ejecutándose a pantalla completa y jugando con el tamaño del navegador, puede verse que todo funciona correctamente.

En tu ejemplo habría que tener en cuenta varias cosas:

- En tu elemento `.fondo_slide` tienes aplicado un `width`, pero no un `height`. Dado que los `<div>` por defecto poseen un `display:block` si no le asignas un `height` no se te va a visualizar el elemento si no tiene nada en su interior. En mi ejemplo se lo añadí, además de un `background-color` para que el elemento pueda verse (aunque en mi ejemplo le añada un texto a través de la propiedad `content` unida a la pseudo-clase `before`).
- Al elemento le estás aplicando un `top` y un `left`. Esta manera de posicionar un elemento necesita tener asignado un `position`, ya sea `absolute` o `relative` para que estos valores signifiquen algo. En mi ejemplo le añadí un `position:relative`.
- No nos muestras el resto de las reglas **CSS** que podrían estar interviniendo, por lo que el problema lo puedes estar teniendo en una colisión de `mediaqueries` (tener definidas otras reglas que afecten a esos tamaños en otros lugares de tu **CSS**, provocando que se apliquen algunas inesperadas).

```css
.fondo_slide {
  top: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.fondo_slide:before {
  content: 'Normal';
}

@media (max-width: 1440px){
.fondo_slide {
    top: 65px;
    width: 285px;
    left: 143px;
 }
 
 .fondo_slide:before {
    content: '1440px';
  }
}

 @media (max-width: 1280px){
.fondo_slide {
    top: 35px;
    width: 265px;
    left: 122px;
 }
 
 .fondo_slide:before {
    content: '1280px';
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px){
.fondo_slide {
    top: 37px;
    width: 187px;
    left: 93px;
    content: '1024px';
 }
 
 .fondo_slide:before {
    content: '1024px';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo_slide"></div>
```